# Adding Archiva repo to Ivy

Tags: ivy, archiva

I'm trying to add an archiva-repo to ivy buit it doesn't work.

Here are the used files:

*ivy.xml*

```
<ivy-module version="2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info organisation="in.ex" module="ivy-example" status="integration">
</info>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6" />
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

*ivysettings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="archiva" />
<credentials host="http://myarchiva/archiva/" realm="Apache Archiva"
    username="user" passwd="pwd" />
<property name="archiva-internal"
    value="http://myarchiva/archiva/repository/internal" />
<resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="archiva" m2compatible="true" root="${archiva-internal}" />
</resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

*build.xml*

```
<project name="ivy example" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

<target name="resolve" description="resolve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml" />
    <ivy:retrieve />
</target>

</project>
```

When i run the ant task, the following error is shown:

```
module not found: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6
==== archiva: tried
http://myarchiva/archiva/repository/internal/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.pom
-- artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6!commons-lang.jar:
http://myarchiva/archiva/repository/internal/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
```

It seems, that the commons-lang was not found but it is still there. When i try the url in my browser, I'm getting the jar.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You may get a little more info from Ivy by using "-d" on the Ant command line.  Probably nothing useful, though.

Comment: any errors in archiva logs ?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran ant -d, I saw an error

```
[ivy:retrieve] CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=http://
```

Took me ages to work out why I couldn't get artifacts from my local Archiva.

Answer (score -1):

Only resolver you have is your internal repo. and there is no commons-lang-2.6.jar in your repo. Simplest way to resolve this is add default maven repo. resolver after your own resolver like

```
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" />
```

Or you can download and manually add the file too.

Update:
Also the value of realm should be the following and it's case sensitive

```
    "Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository"
```

Comment: i've follow your solution, and everything seems work fine, but when i do the build ant says that it find every artifact, even if some artifacts are not present in my archiva repo, do you know why?

Comment: The question said "When i try the url in my browser, I'm getting the jar." so clearly they DO have commons-lang-2.6.jar in their repo